# Laravel downloading files from storage causing internal server error (Status code 500)

Tags: php, laravel

I created a new local disk under `/storage/app/uploads` in

**Filesystems.php:**

```
 'uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/uploads'),
    ],
```

Now when I try to download a zip file in an ajax request, my `DownloadController` throws a:

> Internal server error Status code 500

Any idea? I couldn't find the problem. Thanks in advance.

**Code snippet of the DownloadController:**

```
public function verify(Request $request, $hash)
{
    // Some sql queries here
    $headers = ["Content-Type"=>"application/zip"];
    return $response()->download(storage_path()."/app/uploads/test.zip", "test.zip",$headers);
}
```

> EDIT

I discovered that:

```
return Storage::disk('uploads')->download("test.zip","zip.zip");
```

will work when the call is not made in an ajax. I somehow have to get the ajax to get the file and download it

**An image of the storage:**
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the permission of the uploads folder?

Comment: No I didn't change them. Is there anything to change? The file should just be downloadable using this method after authentication

Comment: use storage path within your public folder: `'root' => storage_path('app/public/uploads'),`

Comment: try removing the `$` in `$response()`

Comment: @ChristopheHubert does not download the file I changed the path in the public folder and removed the $

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#downloading-files) on how to download the files, you need to specify your storage driver and then call the download method:

```
return Storage::disk('uploads')->download('test.zip');
```

Comment: This doesn't throw an error but doesn't download the file. Do I have to do something in the AJAX in the template?